How to reassign values based on grouping and dates (R)
I have a dataframe that looks like the following:
grp1 <- c('A','A','A','A','A','A',
          'B','B','B','B','B','B',
          'C','C','C','C','C','C')
grp2 <- c('PQ2','PQ2','PQ2','PQ2','PQ2','PQ2',
          'PL2','PL2','PL2','PL2','PL2','PL2',
          'PN2','PN2','PN2','PN2','PN2','PN2')
grp3 <- c('ML2','ML2','ML2','ML2','ML2','ML2',
          'MP2','MP2','MP2','MP2','MP2','MP2',
          'MO2','MO2','MO2','MO2','MO2','MO2')
date <- c('2022-04-04','2022-04-05','2022-04-11','2022-04-12','2022-04-18','2022-04-19',
          '2022-04-04','2022-04-05','2022-04-11','2022-04-12','2022-04-18','2022-04-19',
          '2022-04-04','2022-04-05','2022-04-11','2022-04-12','2022-04-18','2022-04-19')

count <- c(1206, 1432, 333, 292, 1120, 1345, 1100, 1150, 245, 423, 1500, 1400, 1300, 1200, 400, 402, 1100, 1107)

df <- data.frame(cbind(grp1, grp2, grp3, date, count))

For each group, I want to reassign the count values that fall on April 11th to match the values that were seen on April 4th.  And the same thing for April 12th values - I want them to be reassigned to the values that were seen on April 5th.
I know I need to use a case statement or ifelse function to make this work, but I am a little stuck on the logic for how to write this out.  Is there an easier way or a package that does this in one step?

By "match" do you mean you want the values to be exactly the same? By the way, you do not need to cbind() your vectors in a data frame.

Yes so the 333 would become 1206 and the 292 would become 1432.  Then, the 245 would become 1100 and the 423 would become 1150 and so on...

A better way to create your data frame would be data.frame(grp1, grp2, ...) rather than use cbind. See my comment below.

I am not 100% certain how you define a group, so I am assuming here it is all columns that start with "grp".
library(dplyr)

df |>
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) |>
  group_by(pick(starts_with("grp"))) |>
  mutate(count = coalesce(count[match(date - 7, date)], count)) |>
  ungroup()

This works by trying to find a date 7 days prior and taking the corresponding count value, if available.

Alternatively, you can do:
df |>
  mutate(date = as.Date(date)) |>
  group_by(pick(starts_with("grp"))) |>
  mutate(count = case_match(date, 
                            as.Date("2022-04-11") ~ count[match("2022-04-04", date)],
                            as.Date("2022-04-12") ~ count[match("2022-04-05", date)],
                            .default = count)) |>
  ungroup()

Output
   grp1  grp2  grp3  date       count
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <date>     <chr>
 1 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-04 1206 
 2 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-05 1432 
 3 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-11 1206 
 4 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-12 1432 
 5 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-18 333  
 6 A     PQ2   ML2   2022-04-19 292  
 7 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-04 1100 
 8 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-05 1150 
 9 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-11 1100 
10 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-12 1150 
11 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-18 245  
12 B     PL2   MP2   2022-04-19 423  
13 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-04 1300 
14 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-05 1200 
15 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-11 1300 
16 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-12 1200 
17 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-18 400  
18 C     PN2   MO2   2022-04-19 402  


Be careful about using cbind, which creates a matrix. Matrices in R are atomic, meaning all elements must be the same type. This will silently coerce your values to strings, in this case. You can see this in my output (and is also the reason I needed to convert date to a date object). The count column is of type character.

Thanks for the tip!  I'm not trying to shift values up or down, I'm just trying to replace values on a date with values from another date by group

A group is just a unique combination of the values of grp1, grp2, and grp3.  In my actual data, they have different names.  I just chose grp1, grp2, ... for ease of use in this example.

If you're trying to shift all count values up by two rows within each group, you could do something like the following:
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(grp1, grp2, grp3, date, count)

df %>%
  # convert date to Date type for sorting
  dplyr::mutate(
    date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
  ) %>% 
  # ensure sorted
  dplyr::arrange(grp1, grp2, date) %>%
  # for each group
  dplyr::group_by(grp1, grp2) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    # shift all count values up 2 within each group
    new.count = dplyr::lead(count, n = 2),
    # optionally, replace NAs with the original value
    new.count2 = dplyr::if_else(!is.na(new.count), new.count, count)
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()


I'm not trying to shift values up or down, I'm just trying to replace values on a date with values from another date by group.
